# Configure MAMP PRO to run Magento 2 on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, mamp

I'm trying to run magento 2 with Nginx on Mamp. But I'm always getting error in logs

> 2021/02/19 12:38:13 [error] 10836#0: *211 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: magento.loc, request: "GET /en_gb HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI_php7.3.24.sock:", host: "magento.loc"

[image]

[image]

I tried to add this params and did nginx reload, it didn't helped. The same error appears.
[image]

What I can do to resolve it????

Comment: Double check your buffer sizes against the ones here https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud-docker/blob/1.2.1/images/nginx/1.19/etc/vhost.conf#L161 check all the buffer related values though

Answer (score 0):

The buffer size options you have highlighted will resolve this error.

Here is an example MAMP config for Magento https://gist.github.com/apiworks/bbb8ec03843e1926089055d634a2c4db

Check your nginx configuration, in my nginx magento2 site configs (I am not using MAMP) these buffer options are always in the `server` section.